# Spawning several processes and interact with them in a non-blocking way

Tags: python, subprocess, pexpect

I need to spawn several processes (the same process more than one time) and interact with them in a non blocking way. Since each process is a python script which wants input from command line, I also need some expect-like way to interact with it.

Pexpect would have been perfect, if only it didn't let me wait until the end of the called method.

Is subprocess what I need? I already tried to use it in an expect-like way but I totally failed.

This is the code with Pexpect:

```
def test_applying_policies( self ):
    root = pexpect.spawn ('pyretic.py -f -m p0 pyretic.step_four root password') 
    root.logfile = sys.stdout 
    root.expect('How many new users do you want to create?')
    root.sendline(str(num_users))
    root.expect('dumb_network_created')

    self.users_list = []
    x=1
    try:
        while x<=num_users:
            temp = controller(x)
            self.users_list.append(temp)
            x+=1
    except:
        for user in self.users_list:
            user.close()
        root.sendline('q')
        root.terminate()

    x=0
    while x<num_users:
        res = self.users_list[x].install_policy(policy_modules[x]) 
        #I got stuck here, even if the install_policy 
        #method does not return any value
        self.assertTrue(res)
        x+=1

    for user in self.users_list:
        user.close()
    root.sendline('q')
    root.terminate()
```

This is the Controller Class:

```
class controller():

def __init__(self,name):
    s = 'pyretic.py -f -m p0 pyretic.step_four user' + 
                    str(name) + ' password'+ str(name)

    self.p = pexpect.spawn(s)
    self.p.logfile = sys.stdout
    self.name = name
    self.p.expect('dumb_network_created')

def close(self):
    self.p.sendline( 'q' )
    self.p.terminate()

def install_policy(self, policy):

    self.p.sendline( 'a' )
    self.p.expect('enter the name of the module:')
    self.p.sendline(policy)
    res = self.p.expect ( ['NACK','ACK',pexpect.TIMEOUT] )

    if res == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to wait until the end of the called method, it would seem that you wish to use that method in a way that is in fact blocking.

Comment: Actually I don't want that. My intention is to call the _install_policy_ method without waiting for the result, in order to have the controllers working in parallel.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I just forgot to add you in the previous comment...

Comment: @danieledc Consider using zeromq. It allows very easy network or unix socket communication and can handle your workers in any way you wish. Instead of command line parameters (which you still can use at worker startup) you would use messages and could alse have feedback from workers, if you care about it.

Comment: 1. Have you tried to change `pyretic.py` to be able to import it instead of running it as a subprocess? Then you could use `threading`, `multiprocessing` modules to run the code concurrently 2. Or you could use `timeout` parameter for `pexpect` methods e.g., `p.read_nonblocking(size=100, timeout=1)` tries to read at most 100 bytes in a second or raises `TIMEOUT` exception otherwise, to avoid blocking for long. 3. Or just run `.install_policy()` in a different thread.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for the tips, I hadn't thought about the first two options before. I'll give it a try. About the third one, actually that was the solution I've adopted until now, but it's not perfect: running subprocess instances in different thread?!?!?! I don't actually need it.

Comment: @danieledc: about the third option: you are not running subprocesses in a different thread. I've suggested to *wait for I/O from a child process* in a different thread (Python threads work very well in this case (GIL is released)). `.install_policy()` doesn't start a new subprocess: it just writes/reads input/output to/from the existing subprocess.

Comment: I've been thinking about adding support for asyncio to Pexpect, which might help with this.